# Public service announcement: Keeping the Workplace Professional

Tags: discussion, faq, site-policy

### Be nice.

Stack Exchange has a [Be Nice](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice) policy. The Workplace is no exception to this policy.

Lately we moderators have been spending a lot of time dealing with comments and posts including such things as name-calling, personal attacks, condescending answers to sincere questions, and other content inappropriate for a professional site.

All members of this community are expected to abide by the [Be Nice](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice) policy. If you have any questions please ask, either here, on another meta post, or [The Workplace Chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3060/the-water-cooler).

### How can you help?

When you see rudeness or inappropriate content, please don't engage or directly respond. Instead flag the comment/post(s) so that we can take care of it.

The members of this community have worked hard to build a site where people can receive good, professional answers to their workplace questions. Please help us maintain the high standards that people have come to expect from Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: As I see it, people who can't get along with other are one of main reasons for the very existence of this site. So naturally we become a number of such people here at _the Workplace_. Practising what we preach here can very well become the proof of the purpose of this site, which is nice.