# Reason for deleting comments?

Tags: discussion, comments

Several days ago (perhaps week before last?), I posted a comment on this answer:

https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/36407/16724

As closely as I can recall, my comment was:

> This answer is the most generous/gracious/nicest answer here. Although, if you have two of the same cup, how can you tell them apart?

Someone later replied something along the lines of:

> Cups like this often come in different varieties, so you could get one that is slightly different.

(That wasn't very close to the text, but that was the basic point.)

Those comments have since been deleted, and I'm very confused about why. My original comment raised what I considered to be a valid point (How do you tell them apart?). I suppose the mention of it being nice/generous/gracious might be considered chatty, but when I originally made the comment, I felt that pointing it out was important since the answer was sitting at a net -4 votes. (I clearly am not the only one to hold that opinion, as it has since received a net +24 votes and is sitting at +20.) The second comment was purely useful; it addressed the concern I raised (or at least attempted to).

Could someone shed some light on the reason for deleting these comments?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What "comments" are not . . .](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/72/what-comments-are-not)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are, at present, [26 deleted comments](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2748/168) on that answer.  If yours and the response had been the only ones they probably wouldn't have attracted any notice, but they ended up as part of a larger set of comments that had largely descended to arguments about what is or isn't passive-aggressive, assertions and counter-claims that this rewards bad behavior, and some heated comments that were definitely over the ["be nice" line](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2979/168).  Not *yours*, to be clear, but many others.

Your comment asked a good question.  The ideal response would be for somebody to edit the answer to address that concern by adding a note that it might come in a different color for easy distinction.  Comments aren't meant to be long-lived (durable content should be in questions and answers), and in the end, while cleaning up the pile there, I decided that this particular point wasn't all that critical here (other answers address ways to distinguish your mug from others').

That still leaves the part of your comment that said that this is a kind/gracious response.  A later comment covered that in a little more detail so I didn't think we need two, so I deleted yours.

There was nothing wrong with your comment *on its own*; it was just a victim of circumstances.  I'm sorry this caused you any upset.

Comment: Thank you. Appreciate the explanation. Per your suggestion here, I've submitted an edit incorporating that information. (It has to be approved, of course.) I've also deleted my most recent comment, as it strayed into the debate you mentioned.

Comment: @jpmc26 thanks for the edit.  Approved.  And thanks for understanding.  The Workplace has something of a comments problem, and I hadn't noticed that a new user might be surprised by this.

Comment: I can see why that might be the case. I come from StackOverflow, where the issues we tend to face are more concrete. Workplace is by its very nature somewhat more opinionated and appeals to a wider audience, so I can see why you'd need to be a bit more Draconian with comments. My apologies for any trouble I caused.

Comment: Oh, it's no trouble -- I would much rather that people ask about something that makes them confused or unhappy instead of just either walking away or stewing about it.

Comment: @jpmc26 Just a note from another of the mods, we get a lot of comments flagged and end up deleting trains of comments somewhat often. These tend to have many comments (we regularly delete 10+ comment threads). We are bound to hit some good comments in the crossfire, especially in the longer threads which are completely off topic or in many cases inappropriate. Thanks for asking about it here and showing grace!