# Feature request: Prompt to include a requerst to include country of origin

Tags: feature-request

Since different countries can have wildly different labor laws and customs, I think a prompt to request the user to enter country of origin either in the post itself or the tags would be of great help.

We often see in the comments requests for the country, or worse, answers posted with the assumption that the OP is in a different nation where the laws and customs are very different.  India, for example, where relieving letters are required, getting answers which not taking that into account can be very bad advice.

A recent example was regarding quitting or getting fired.  In the USA, getting fired for cause will make you ineligible for benefits, where in other countries, it may not.

Could we get a prompt asking for country?

Comment: to the downvoter:  Why do you think this is a bad idea?

Comment: [Stack Overflow is trialling an Ask A Question wizard](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/378057/254830) which aims to prompt people for basic information they might regularly not provide. It's one of the features that can be rolled out to other sites now that the themes are unified. Perhaps that could be applied to resolve this problem once it's out, if nothing else happens for this in the meantime.

Comment: Fully agree. There's currently a prime example in the HNQ: https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/169948/how-to-refuse-constant-outside-office-hours-meetings-politely OP has a German-sounding user name, the top answers assumed that they were in Europe, and only later was is revealed that OP is in China, which has vastly different employee protection laws and a significantly different culture with respect to work-life balance.

Answer (score 4):

I would definitely be in support of this. This conversation came up a few years ago [here at Workplace Meta](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3216/the-workplace-is-a-worldwide-site/3217#3217), which prompted me to [request a new feature on Meta SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/260738/custom-recommended-tags-list-for-individual-se-sites). Like most feature requests, it unfortunately never got enough attention for anything to come of it.