# Is it expected that I cannot comment on questions or answers, having reputation 1,986?

Tags: discussion, support

My reputation on workplace is currently 1,986. The commenting privilege starts at 50. However, I can't comment on any questions or answers—there is no "add a comment" link on any of them for me.

Is this expected? Have I been explicitly denied commenting privileges? If there is some kind of problem I would appreciate the chance to hear about it and address it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> there is no "add a comment" link on any of them for me.

It's because currently it reads *"suggest Improvements"* (on main site):

[image]

The reason is stated in this post: [Experiment running: a comment by any other name](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5320/73791)

You can leave comments by pressing the *"suggest improvements"* link :) Just, try to stick to *what comments are for*. **That is, to suggest improvements or ask for clarification.**

Comment: Ohhhhhh... I saw those and thought, for some reason, those links were to edit the content of the item, which I did not want to do.

Perhaps the [Privileges](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) page can have its wording updated so someone who at least goes searching the help will figure out what's going on (make sure it still has the word "comment" to be searchable). Alternately, perhaps a different link text that doesn't sound like "edit this post in a to-be-approved form".

Comment: Ah! Found one more thing. This additional mismatch was part of the disconnect: "suggest improvements |  show 7 more comments". If they're called "comments" then clearly "suggest improvements" is not the same thing. How about just "show 7 more" or maybe "show 7 more improvement suggestions"?

Comment: @CodeSeeker it's just a temporary experiment, so changing those things on the priviledges may not be worth it. However, the show X more comments thing is really relevant, but again, bound to the temporal limits of the experiment :)