# Why can I not comment?

Tags: support, comments

I was trying to add a comment to [this question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/116571/new-job-no-task-assigned-yet), but found only "suggest improvements" and "show all comments" links; none for adding new comments.

This appears to be a new thing. I'm not 100% sure, because I may be confusing it with other stacks where I *can* comment and may just not have noticed that I can't do that *here*. Why though?

I seem to have [sufficient reputation to have earned the privilege](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); have I done something to have it revoked?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The comment button has been renamed in an attempt to encourage more appropriate use of the comments system for the site.

Please see this Meta thread for more information

[Experiment running: a comment by any other name](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5320/experiment-running-a-comment-by-any-other-name)

Comment: Ah ok, I have read that and now I understand. (I do not agree though, but that's something I have commented on at your linked post.) I also note that, here, it _is_ named "add a comment", so that inconsistency just makes it all the more confusing.

Comment: @KlaymenDK yeah, it's a temporary experiment, not (yet) a permanent change, so they only changed it in the one place.  Besides, comments are usually more appropriate on meta, where we discuss issues about the site.