# Commenting now shows "suggest improvements" which doesn't really make sense if I am the author of the question

Tags: bug

I noticed  Workplace StackExchange, instead of "add a comment", I see new copy for "suggest improvements".

I like that change but it doesn't really make sense if I am the author of the question -- I was wondering if this was a bug? I don't see it in all StackExchanges so not sure if this is configured specifically for Workplace StackExchange. Feel free to close if not an issue.

Comment: It's no bug, it's an experiment: https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5320/73791

Comment: If you are the author of the question, why would you wish to comment on it?

Comment: @JoeStrazzere to respond to comments who have follow up questions that might not make sense to add to the question itself such as this reply xD

Answer (score 1):

Comments should be treated as ephemeral.  This basically means that the questions and answers should really stand on their own - a future reader with the same question as you shouldn't have to read the comments in order to learn the answer to their question.

If someone has made a suggestion to your question or is seeking clarification, then it means that information isn't in the question.

While you could add another comment/suggestion to answer those concerns, the ideal place to answer is in the question itself.  The comments aren't there to clarify the question - they're there as a prompt to you to clarify the question (or for someone else to edit your question).